# Navigation NavController in Ionic 2 app SOLVED! but not in Ionic 3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, navigation, ionic2

I'm building an app with Ionic 2 and my question relates the navigation, it is not easy to explain but I'll try:

I have a page (MyFilePage), with a list of files from a cloud, in which I recall the navCtrl.push() on it, for recursive navigation in folders. On this page I have an ion-fab button who sends me, with push(), to another page (UplaodPage), with the list of file in the memory's device. In this page I recall the method push() on it, as the other page, for recursive navigation in folders. After that I select the file I want to upload, and what I would to do, is return to the last MyFilePage visited, (the one where I make the uplaod).

I post an image, [ionic 2 app strucure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e4hF.png) , that may clarify the situation.

Thanks

EDIT:
This works nice on Ionic 2 with the method push(page: any, params?: any, opts?: NavOptions, done?: Function);, but not in Ionic 3, that have the method push(page: Page | string, params?: any, opts?: NavOptions, done?: Function): Promise;, where page is type of Page|string and the method getByIndex() returns a ViewController.

Anyone have a solution?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep pages:

1- first you need to get the index of the page you want to back to and save in a provider(recommended) or storage.

```
let index = this.navCtrl.indexOf(this.navCtrl.getActive());
```

2- then you can go to the saved page like this:

```
let selectedPage = this.navCtrl.getByIndex(index);
this.navCtrl.push(selectedPage );
```

and if you like to remove those pages:

1- first you need to get the index of the page you want to back to and also a counter when ever you push a page. then save them in a provider(recommended) or storage.

2- then you can go to the selected page and remove the other like this:

```
this.navCtrl.remove(startIndex+1, removeCount);
```

for more info check [NavController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/).

Comment: With your suggestions, the value of index is always -1, browsing any page. And when I initialize the variable selectedPage with this.navCtrl.getByIndex (index); , where index always has a value of -1, this variable is undefined.

Comment: You must replace the view variable! I also change the answer.

Comment: As soon as I have some time, I'll try and let you know. Of course, I had replaced the view variable, but with this.viewCtrl.index. Thanks!